# Is there a good SQL Diagram Editor/Drawing Mac App Tool?

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation, database

Does anyone know a comprehensive Mac app to create SQL Diagramms?
I think http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/ is quite good, but it's a little bit too basic.

I would like to create the database schema, the relations between the tables (including labels for e.g. n:m relations), add comments, export to SQL, and so on to run from my Mac.

Comment: Give [yed](http://www.yworks.com/products/yed) a try. It's free

Answer (score 17):

[MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/) is good enough for most programming demands. You can create **EER Model** and can also synchronize the model with DB Changes or vice versa. You can use it with no cost as it's a open-source application. I have been using MySQL for a year and it is very useful for me. I recommend it to you if you don't need any enterprise features and performance.

Comment: I know MySQL Workbench already, please look at the comments :) Actually i love MySQL Workbench, but there could be a few more features (look at my comment above or see my Workbench question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946161/how-to-draw-relationship-lines-between-columns)

Comment: I see! As for me, I don't export to Image File. But I use Workbench and hover mouse cursor to highlight relationship lines instead.

Comment: You are right, MySQL Workbench is a great modeler, and free.  You can generate the DDL and modify by hand for SQLite, although that it ugly...but at least it lets you document.

Answer (score 9):

The only Mac only tool I know (and I would love to hear of others here) is [SQLEditor](http://www.malcolmhardie.com/sqleditor/). Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any support for Stored Procedures or other objects beyond tables and views.

There are also cross-platform solutions (mostly Java-based). In a recent search I evaluated [DBWrench](http://www.dbwrench.com/) and [DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/). When all was said and done, I decided to stay with a Windows solution running under Parallels.

Comment: Thanks for SQLEditor. I'll give it a try. I'm currently trying MySQL Workbench for Mac and it's really great, except some visual "bugs" (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946161/how-to-draw-relationship-lines-between-columns)

Comment: Except, I don't use MySQL.

Comment: Which Windows solution do you use?

Comment: @Slevin: [Toad Data Modeler](http://www.quest.com/toad-data-modeler/). Very powerful. Cranky interface. Internal documentation of scripting language mostly in Czech.

Comment: I've made my choice: SQLEditor is great! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 4):

[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) is great, though I found that in a lot of cases [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) works wonderful, especially if you're not so much into "doing it painfully correct according to theory learnt at university" but rather getting the job done.

Comment: OmniGraffle is a little bit too basic for modelling ERD. I don't want doing it painfully correct, but some features are missing ;)

Comment: Dunno why you wouldn't want to do it "painfully correct", and save your self true pain down the road. People and their half-baked shortcuts. Pfff

Comment: @Volte, so what mac app do you suggest then?

Comment: @Sarel, my comment does not imply a suggestion. It was a—wait for it—comment with regards to "doing it painfully correct".

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com) line of products. I use [Navicat Premium](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_premium/premium_overview.html) and it's a really great all-in-one tool for many DBs, including MySQL, Postgres, SQLITE, Oracle, and MS SQL Server. It includes a Model tab where you can view and edit existing DBs or create *de novo* ones, sketch everything out, define relationships, export SQL, have access to an auto-layout function, and all sorts of other goodies.

There are several versions stepping up to the Premium product, including a separate [Data Modeler](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_datamodeler/modeler_overview.html) program, so you'll have to browse around to see what fits your needs. It will set you back a little bit of cash, depending on the version, but you can download a 30-day free trial to make sure it's what you need.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried it out and seen that the mac version is just a wine port. Also, it crashes if i start the app...

Comment: that's strange, my version is a native app. I just downloaded http://download2.navicat.com/download/modeleress010_en.dmg and it was native as far as I could tell. What version of OSX are you running? I'm on 10.8.2...

Comment: The app has a whole bunch of nib files in the Resources, so it looks really native for me. It works great for me.  (I got it from the App Store.) The Linux version is Wine, though.

Comment: I don't get it... something went wrong. Now it works... :)

Answer (score 2):

The free SQL tool of choice for me is [SQuirreLSQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net). It is a Java application, but very responsive, and you can install both DB drivers and plugins from it, and one of them allows for reverse-engineering and diagramming databases.

[Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio.html) runs on Mac OS X as a mixed Cocoa/Java application, with native performance, and includes Entity-Relationship modeling capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I also use Vertabelo and I can recommend it, too. It is 100% web-based. You can work on your models either in Chrome, or in Safari (the support for Safari browser was added a few month ago). Vertabelo's graphical tools for designing database models are simply amazing! Simple and intuitive, and yet very comprehensive and professional. There's no desktop license, no downloads and no installation. You can work remotely from any computer connected to the web. If you would like to get to know how Vertabelo works, you can try it without any registration: https://my.vertabelo.com/try

Answer (score 2):

[DBSchema](http://www.dbschema.com/) is also awesome. Best thing is that you can do reverse engineering as well as modeling together at once. After you change the diagram, you change the database; you can import those changes back in the diagram.

The only flaw is ordering of column names in the diagrams - that do not necessarily match with the ordinality of the column names in the real database if you do so.

I would rate it to be one of the super nice applications.

Comment: +1 - Wish I had known about DbSchema sooner. I wasted so much time with Navicat and SQL Power Architect. DbSchema is Java-based (Groovy??), but it looks really good and has a ton of useful features.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.yworks.com/en/index.html, might not be what you are looking for but it has ER modelling and others...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Surely copy-pasting information which is available directly on their website is a) a waste of time and b) irrelevant if the information itself changes. The link is one of the few things that is likely to go unchanged for a very long time. I appreciate your comment but is all the other answers have user opinion mixed in with fact and sometimes masked as fact. I have merely given the link for reference then the OP can make their own call.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Vertabelo](http://www.vertabelo.com). Vertabelo is an online database designer working under Chrome developed by company I work for.

The most important feature of this tool is that it allow to share database models across the team and collaborate on them via web browser.

Others Vertabelo features include:

- Model versioning
- Support for PosgreSql, MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, DB2, SQLite, HSQLDB
- Dynamic/Visual search
- Live database model validation
- Reverse engineering

Vertabelo is free to use for smaller projects (up to 3 models and 20 tables within each model) and have commercial versions for larger database projects.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred tool for modeling in OS X, is [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/) (VP-UML). They have a free community edition, which is great for creating ERD - but if you want to generate the DDL from your ERD, you'll need to purchase the standard edition.

It's also cross-platform, so that's another boon.

Answer (score 0):

[DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io), which is open source, does a good job of making ER diagrams and can connect to just about every database backend. It’s also a decent database viewer/editor.

[image: Example ER Diagram]